# Create Modal Window to Chose Document Content Type

Tags: 2010, document-library, content-type, ribbon

I'm working in SP 2010.

I have created three new document content types. I want to force the user to select a content type when they are adding a new document to the library. As it is right now, they would have to know to click the down arrow under "New document" in the ribbon, and then select their content type.

Is there a way to change the click options for the "New Document" button in the ribbon and also the "+ Add New Document" link that appears within the page.

This solution like [this](https://spandothers.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/sharepoint-replacing-the-new-document-button-with-something-functional/) would work but the user never posted the how-to & code. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can remove the 'New Document' button so only the content types buttons are shown.  This can be done out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an article in mind that goes over this process? @SMerchant

Comment: I have now provided the steps to achieve this

Comment: did you manage to achieve this?

Comment: @SMerchant This solution doesn't quite do what I need it to do. It may be because I'm using SharePoint 2010. I still have the "New Document" button. I don't see a way to make each of the content types their own button in the ribbon without being in the dropdown menu. I'm going to try and add an image to the original question so you can see what it looks like on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete or change the visibility for the 'New Document' content type and you can also reorder it. Steps below but if you want more information, it is available [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

[image]

**Under List Setting - Click 'Change New Button Order..'**
[image]

**Untick the Visible or if you want to reorder change the position from the dropdown**
[image]

**Outcome**

[image]