# Change drop down list menu behavior

Tags: list, hide-elements, context-menu

I Have a list and it is displaying the following menu:

[image]

If the user clicks on "New" word it uses the default "item" content type, but I want to disable it and also hide "Item" from the options so that users do not select it.

Users should only be able to select any of the 3 content types below (Build, Optimize or IT).

Is there any javascript or something that may help here or what alternatives do you suggest.

Your support will be really appreciated.

Comment: duplicate:  Please see this for more details https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214716/create-modal-window-to-chose-document-content-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the List settings, under 'Content Types' click on option 'Change new button and default content type' 
You will then be able to change the default content type, you can also set the order of your content types.